# Reason behind WinHttpOpenRequest default url encoding behaviour

Tags: winapi, winhttp

Part of my application relies on a HTTP client which is based on the Win32 API.

Each HTTP query is initiated with calls to `WinHttpOpenRequest` like

```
std::wstring method = L"POST";
std::wstring path = L"/foo/bar%baz";
WinHttpOpenRequest(
            m_connectionHandler,
            method.c_str(),
            path.c_str(),
            NULL,
            WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
            WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
            WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);
```

Until now, I was relying on the default behavior of `WinHttpOpenRequest` for properly percent encode the query.

I just discovered that the literal character `%` was left unescaped by default and that I must pass `WINHTTP_FLAG_ESCAPE_PERCENT` as additional flag.

I do not really get *why* this API encodes every reserved characters correctly except for the percent character itself. Are there any pragmatic reasons behind this choice? And can I safely use this additionnal flag, or are there any pitfalls I cannot see?

The only reason I can imagine is to avoid a double percent encoding with the default behavior, i.e I would already percent encoded my query, and the `WinHttpOpenRequest` cannot guess whether the percent characters it reads are the result of a percent encoding or not.

Comment: If the percent sign would always be URL-encoded, you wouldn't be able to use it for URL-encoding purposes yourself, e.g. `%20` would then be converted into `%%20`, probably not what you intended.

Comment: @IInspectable I understand, but I would have expected to disable entirely all url encoding on `WinHttpOpenRequest` with WINHTTP_FLAG_ESCAPE_DISABLE if I had done the encoding before calling this function. Or is it to allow some sort fo mixed mode, i.e some reserved charaters are already encoded but not all?

Comment: If you aren't providing any flags, `WinHttpOpenRequest` can consume any resource locator. Unsafe characters get URL-encoded, and URL-encoded sequences are left alone. This covers the vast majority of use cases, including the case where some parts of a URL are URL-encoded, while other parts still contain unsafe characters. This can happen when your application pieces together a URL from different sources (both application code as well as libraries). To opt-in to special treatment, you have to provide flags. This follows the guiding principle of optimizing for the most common use case.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer makes much sense and it answers everything I had in mind. Feel free to fill an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`%` It can also be used as an escape character, for example, you cannot print out '%' just with `printf("%")` but `printf("%%")`.

If you block escape function of the `%`, As what does IInspectable say, You will not be able to use the escape function like %20, And other more: %2B, %2F, %3F, %3D, %21...

Description on [msdn document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpopenrequest), Flag `WINHTTP_FLAG_ESCAPE_PERCENT` means

> The string passed in for pwszObjectName is converted from an LPCWSTR
>   to an LPSTR. All unsafe characters are converted to an escape sequence
>   including the percent symbol.

But ,by default,

> all unsafe characters except the percent symbol are
>   converted to an escape sequence.